# How send wfs transaction data on json format in Openlayers?

Tags: wfs-t, openlayers-2

I use a wfs layer in my project with openlayers as follows:

```
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

me.point = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        url: 'point/read',
        featureType: "point",
        featureNS: "http://salam.opengeo.org",
        geometryName: "the_geom",
        readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({}),
    })
});
```

I edit some features and when I want to sync with server it send a request as follow:

```
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:Update typeName="feature:itsme" xmlns:feature="http://iran.me">
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>
            <wfs:Value>
                <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
                    <gml:pos>49.02405689339376 34.858924130844805</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
            </wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:Name>name</wfs:Name>
            <wfs:Value>Salam Bar Hossein</wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="point.3"/>
        </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Update>
```

I want to config the `point layer` to send transaction data with `json` format.

**How do I do?**

Comment: I do not know any WFS server that would accept anything else than GML for transactions.

Comment: out of curiosity what GIS server are you using? GeoServer?

Comment: I use both of geoserver and postgis(db)